# check if label.text have had the same text for x amount of seconds?

Tags: c#

Is there a way to check if label.text have had the same text for like 5 seconds? I have a label that is changing its text between "speech" & "silence" depending if the microphone pics up anythinf or not.

for example

```
if(label.text == "silence" for 5 seconds 
{
//do whatever 
}
```

Comment: you can start a timer on form create, everytime 'ontextchanged' you compare it to see if it expanded 5 seconds, if it does you do your code depending on speech & silence

Comment: Wrong code piece. You have "something" that changes the label. Remeber the last time you changed it.if your current time minus that rememberd time is greater equal 5s timediff  you have your solution.

Comment: if you jsut need to reactively check a datetime will do, if you need to proactively check you will need a timer

Answer (score 0):

Depending on *when* you want to check this, one solution is to use a `Timer` with an interval of 5000 ms (5s) combined with the label's `TextChanged` event. Every time `TextChanged` is raised you restart the timer so that it waits another 5 seconds.

**Assuming this is WinForms:**

```
System.Windows.Forms.Timer labelTimer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer() {Interval = 5000};

//You need to attach the Load event handler to your form via the Property Window.
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label1.TextChanged += label1_TextChanged;
    labelTimer.Tick += labelTimer_Tick;
}

private void label1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Restart timer.
    labelTimer.Stop();
    labelTimer.Start();
}

private void labelTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(label1.Text == "silence") {
        //label1 has had the text "silence" for 5 seconds. Do something.
        labelTimer.Stop(); //Wait until the next text change.
    }
}
```

This will run the specified code if the label still has the text `silence` *after* 5 seconds. However if you wish to check this the next time your mic detects input, then this is not the way to go.

Comment: hey, thanks for answer! there is no .Tick available for me, only .Elapsed, is that the same thing? i am using "System.Timers.timer"

Comment: @Weirdrandom : `System.Timers.Timer` is multithreaded and should not be used for checking UI controls. What technology are you using? Windows Forms (WinForms), WPF or something else?

Comment: @Weirdrandom : I'm going to go by the assumption that you're using WinForms, since you check `label.Text` compared to WPF's `label.Content`. I have updated my answer a bit, please let me know if it works. Keep in mind that you also need to attach an event handler (`Form1_Load`) to your form's `Load` event, if you don't have one already.

Comment: @Weirdrandom : Was my answer of any help, or are you still having problems with implementing it?